# Bottom border shaped like \

Tags: javascript, html, css

I`m trying to make hover effect on a box like this image 
[image: solution]

I've tried using transparent top and left border but all i got was bottom border extra triangle pointing the other direction like in this [image: photo]

```css
.news:hover {
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: solid #F4698D 20px;
  border-right: solid #F4698D 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a pseudo element using `::after`. It sits in the bottom left, overlaying the border, and has it's own gradient background that resembles a triangle.

Because the width of the border is used to determine the height, width, and offset of the overlaying element, I've elected to store that number as a CSS variable.

```css
:root {
  --border-width: 10px;
}

div { 
  padding: 50px; 
  border-bottom: var(--border-width) solid transparent;
  border-right: var(--border-width) solid transparent;
  position: relative;
}

div:hover {
  border-color: red;
}

div:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: var(--border-width);
  width:  calc(2 * var(--border-width));
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--border-width));
  left: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, white 50%, red 50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Borders` create that shape that resembles a frame.

Another solution for this effect is to use `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements. You could let them prepared with `opacity: 0`, and then when hovering the element, make it to `opacity: 1`. Like this:

```
.news {
  postision: relative;
}
.news:before { // the bottom line
  bottom: -20px;
  Left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.news:after { // the right line
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
}
.news:after { // here are properties for both pseudo elements
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .32s;
}
.news:hover {
  transform: translate(-20px, 20px);
}
.news:hover:before, .news:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Hope it helps.